# How to make an image fade/slide in after being set from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate my image loading into my page by either sliding or fading. It is being loaded from an array and couldn't find any documentation on this.

JS:

```
  for(i =0; i < 10; i++){

  //instantiates all the initial images.
  $('.penguin'+ i).css("background-image", 'url("imagess/bin.jpg")');


}
```

Comment: [`$(google).fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```js
 for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){

  $('.penguin'+ i).css({backgroundImage: 'url(http://placehold.it/350x150)', display: 'none'});
  $('.penguin'+ i).fadeIn(3000);

}
```

```css
div {
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="penguin0"></div>
<div class="penguin1"></div>
<div class="penguin2"></div>
<div class="penguin3"></div>
<div class="penguin4"></div>
<div class="penguin5"></div>
<div class="penguin6"></div>
<div class="penguin7"></div>
<div class="penguin8"></div>
<div class="penguin9"></div>
```

Comment: @Damian You are welcome. You can adjust the number in parentheses to control the animation speed (in milliseconds).